# All "file" fieldtypes being required since upgrade

Tags: file-uploads, ee2-upgrades, uploads, files

Sorry to keep whining to you guys :)

After upgrading from 2.5.3 to 2.7.0 and then to 2.7.1 in the last few days,
I've discovered that creating new content and editing existing content are both failing with the complaint that "no file was selected for upload". This happens at every instance of the native "file" datatype, and it happens in spite of none of them being marked as required.
A quick scan of the DB confirms that the "not required" setting is also correctly being stored in the exp_channel_fields table.

Oddly, this only happens when the attribute is intended to receive an image. Channels which can take an optional generic file upload can be entered without problems without an attachment being present.

Nothing obvious in the console, nothing at all in the log files.

Anybody seen this before?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in 2.7.1 as well. Pretty sure it wasn't happening in 2.7.0.

Comment: What's worse, for me the error message is not red, so it took me about 10 minutes to figure out why my entries were not saving.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour in 2.7.1. I'm ALSO finding that selecting an image for upload gives me the 'a file of this name already exists' error dialogue, even though no such file exists in the destination directory. Perhaps these bugs are connected? Anyone else getting the latter one?

Comment: Update: my second issue is unrelated and is triggered when a file has invalid characters in its filename. The error message provided is, however, inaccurate and misleading. See bug report https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/17134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a bug, look at this bug report:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19732

Francois

Comment: Spot on, Francois, thank you very much for the quick rescue! I'm really learning to love this site...